# after deployment In Heroku Insert user not working

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-8

I made a normal CRUD app with Laravel 8 , it was working fine in my local machine , but when i deployed it on Heroku , and tried to Insert a user it gives me this error :

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException:
SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation "Utilisateurs" does not exist
LINE 1: select count(*) as aggregate from "Utilisateurs" where "emai...
                                      ^ (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from 
"Utilisateurs" where "email" = heguwenepe@mailinator.com)
```

everything else (editing, updating, Deleting) seems to be working just fine

it also seem to highlight this ligne in my controller for some reason : [image]

**what I have tried :**

- reran migrations
- replaced '' with ""

Validation Rule:

```
"email" => "required|regex:/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ix|unique:Utilisateurs"
```

Comment: are you doing a unique validation on an email field? can you show your validation rules ... as text

Comment: "email" => "required|regex:/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ix|unique:Utilisateurs",

Comment: your table is named `Utilisateurs` or `utilisateurs` ?

Comment: Table name's utilisateurs

Comment: so why did you write `Utilisateurs` and not `utilisateurs` ?  also have you used a database client to see if the table exists currently?

Comment: changing Utilaseurs to utilisateurs fixed that problem, and yes i did check if the Table's existing, but not by using database client

Comment: Glad it worked, good luck and keep enjoying Laravel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the table name exactly as it is was defined: `utilisateurs` not `Utilisateurs`. The case does matter as the identifier is in double quotes in the generated SQL statement.

Always assume case matters and you will have fewer problems down the road.

Comment: gotcha boss , thank you !